# How shoud I do hyperledger fabric performance testing on GCP without suspending warning?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

My project on GCP was suspended after I did hyperledger fabric performance testing with hyperledger caliper. I setup Hyperledger fabric on GCP paid account with 3 Orgs and 6 peers on 12 VMs. I try to do performance testing using hyperledger caliper by sending 10 transactions per sec to 1 peer instance. After 4 hours that I ran caliper, I got email from google that your project is being suspended.

How should I do if I want to test again on GCP without any warnings from google?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with criptocurrency mining operations in GCP you must [apply for an Invoiced Billing Account](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/apply_for_invoiced_billing). Otherwise your account will be detected as fraudulent.

It's the only way to perform the test without triggering the fraud alert.

Comment: But I didn't work with cryptocurrency mining.  My tps is too high?

Comment: Although Hyperledger is not used directly in mining it is used to send blockchain transactions or smart contracts related operations, this is detected as a blockchain operation. Basically all blockchain operations are flagged as mining and trigger this alert for security and legal compliance.